# Prove that every non-zero element of $\Bbb Z_p$ has an order which divides $p-1$.

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

How do I prove this if I am given the information that:
$p \ge 2$ and is a prime and $g$ is an element of order $p − 1$ in $\Bbb Z_p$.

I know I am supposed to use Fermat's little theorem and do a contradiction proof but I am not quite sure on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if, by Fermat's little theorem, $a^p = a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$... what can you say about $a^{p-1}$?

Comment: I thought $a^p-1 = 1 (mod p)$ was fermat's little theorem, but going by what you wrote $a^p-1$ does not equal $a$ i guess?

Comment: They are equivalent statements. If you use the one you wrote, isn't the proof trivial by the definition of "order of an element"?

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 What definition of "order" are you using that makes it trivial?